# Can JAXB marshal by containment at first then marshal by @XmlIDREF for subsequent references?

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2, marshalbyrefobject

I'm wondering if it's possible to annotate my classes so that the first time the marshaller encounters an object, it generates an XML element of the appropriate type, but any subsequent reference to this object by anything else will have an XML IDREF entry created?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can leverage the concept of JAXB's `XmlAdapter` to do something like the following:

**input.xml**

The following is the XML document I will use for this example.  The 3rd `phone-number` entry is a reference to the 1st `phone-number` entry, and the 5th `phone-number` entry is a reference to the 4th.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <phone-number id="A">
        <number>555-AAAA</number>
    </phone-number>
    <phone-number id="B">
        <number>555-BBBB</number>
    </phone-number>
    <phone-number id="A"/>
    <phone-number xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="work-phone-number" id="W">
        <number>555-WORK</number>
        <extension>1234</extension>
    </phone-number>
    <phone-number xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="work-phone-number" id="W"/>
</customer>
```

**Customer**

The customer class maintains a collection of `PhoneNumber` objects.  The same instance of PhoneNumber may appear multiple times in the collection.

```
package forum7587095;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

    @XmlElement(name="phone-number")
    public List<PhoneNumber> getPhoneNumbers() {
        return phoneNumbers;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumbers(List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers) {
        this.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumber**

This is a class that can either appear in the document itself or as a reference.  This will be handled using an `XmlAdapter`.  An XmlAdapter is configured using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.  Since we have specified this adapter at the type/class level it will apply to all properties referencing the `PhoneNumber` class:

```
package forum7587095;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PhoneNumberAdapter.class)
public class PhoneNumber {

    private String id;
    private String number;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        if(null == arg0 || arg0.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        PhoneNumber test = (PhoneNumber) arg0;
        if(!equals(id, test.getId())) {
            return false;
        }
        return equals(number, test.getNumber());
    }

    protected boolean equals(String control, String test) {
        if(null == control) {
            return null == test;
        } else {
            return control.equals(test);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

}
```

**WorkPhoneNumber**

Based on your comment I have added a subclass of `PhoneNumber`.

```
package forum7587095;

public class WorkPhoneNumber extends PhoneNumber {

    private String extension;

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        if(!super.equals(arg0)) {
            return false;
        }
        return equals(extension, ((WorkPhoneNumber) arg0).getExtension());
    }

}
```

**PhoneNumberAdapter**

Below is the implementation of the `XmlAdapter`.  Note that we must maintain if the PhoneNumber object has been seen before.  If it has we only populate the `id` portion of the `AdaptedPhoneNumber` object.

```
package forum7587095;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class PhoneNumberAdapter extends XmlAdapter<PhoneNumberAdapter.AdaptedPhoneNumber, PhoneNumber>{

    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumberList = new ArrayList<PhoneNumber>();
    private Map<String, PhoneNumber> phoneNumberMap = new HashMap<String, PhoneNumber>();

    @XmlSeeAlso(AdaptedWorkPhoneNumber.class)
    @XmlType(name="phone-number")
    public static class AdaptedPhoneNumber {
        @XmlAttribute public String id;
        public String number;

        public AdaptedPhoneNumber() {
        }

        public AdaptedPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
            id = phoneNumber.getId();
            number = phoneNumber.getNumber();
        }

        public PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
            PhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
            phoneNumber.setId(id);
            phoneNumber.setNumber(number);
            return phoneNumber;
        }

    }

    @XmlType(name="work-phone-number")
    public static class AdaptedWorkPhoneNumber extends AdaptedPhoneNumber {

        public String extension;

        public AdaptedWorkPhoneNumber() {
        }

        public AdaptedWorkPhoneNumber(WorkPhoneNumber workPhoneNumber) {
            super(workPhoneNumber);
            extension = workPhoneNumber.getExtension();
        }

        @Override
        public WorkPhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
            WorkPhoneNumber phoneNumber = new WorkPhoneNumber();
            phoneNumber.setId(id);
            phoneNumber.setNumber(number);
            phoneNumber.setExtension(extension);
            return phoneNumber;
        }
}

    @Override
    public AdaptedPhoneNumber marshal(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) throws Exception {
        AdaptedPhoneNumber adaptedPhoneNumber;
        if(phoneNumberList.contains(phoneNumber)) {
            if(phoneNumber instanceof WorkPhoneNumber) {
                adaptedPhoneNumber = new AdaptedWorkPhoneNumber();
            } else {
                adaptedPhoneNumber = new AdaptedPhoneNumber();
            }
            adaptedPhoneNumber.id = phoneNumber.getId();
        } else {
            if(phoneNumber instanceof WorkPhoneNumber) {
                adaptedPhoneNumber = new AdaptedWorkPhoneNumber((WorkPhoneNumber)phoneNumber);
            } else {
                adaptedPhoneNumber = new AdaptedPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            }
            phoneNumberList.add(phoneNumber);
        }
        return adaptedPhoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public PhoneNumber unmarshal(AdaptedPhoneNumber adaptedPhoneNumber) throws Exception {
        PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneNumberMap.get(adaptedPhoneNumber.id);
        if(null != phoneNumber) {
            return phoneNumber;
        }
        phoneNumber = adaptedPhoneNumber.getPhoneNumber();
        phoneNumberMap.put(phoneNumber.getId(), phoneNumber);
        return phoneNumber;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

To ensure the same instance of the `XmlAdapter` is used for the entire `marshal` and `unmarshal` operations we must specifically set an instance of the XmlAdapter on both the `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller`:

```
package forum7587095;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setAdapter(new PhoneNumberAdapter());
        File xml = new File("src/forum7587095/input.xml");
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        System.out.println(customer.getPhoneNumbers().get(0) == customer.getPhoneNumbers().get(2));
        System.out.println(customer.getPhoneNumbers().get(3) == customer.getPhoneNumbers().get(4));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setAdapter(new PhoneNumberAdapter());
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
true
true
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <phone-number id="A">
        <number>555-AAAA</number>
    </phone-number>
    <phone-number id="B">
        <number>555-BBBB</number>
    </phone-number>
    <phone-number id="A"/>
    <phone-number xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="work-phone-number" id="W">
        <number>555-WORK</number>
        <extension>1234</extension>
    </phone-number>
    <phone-number xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="work-phone-number" id="W"/>
</customer>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise for the very detailed response! Is this concept the same if `PhoneNumber` had subclasses? For instance, `Customer` having multiple references to the same `PhoneNumber` subclass instance?

Comment: @holic87 - I have updated my answer so that `PhoneNumber` has subclasses.

Comment: @holic97 - No problem, I have also added a blog post related to this answer:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise. I have a another JAXB-related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7617163/318287) that somewhat ties into this answer. If you're able, would you mind providing some insight on it? Thanks!

Comment: @holic87 - I have just posted an answer to your new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617163/how-to-handle-forward-references-of-xml-idref-with-jaxb-xmladapter-during-unmarsh/7639801#7639801