# Using Spring-WS and JAXB: can't unmarshall subclasses in XML request

Tags: web-services, jaxb, spring-ws, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I have the following in a schema defining the request/response objects used in my web service request:

```
<xs:complexType name="loss" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="lossDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xs:element name="lossDescription" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="autoLoss">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="loss">
            <xs:sequence>
                <!-- autoLoss specific fields... -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="propLoss">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="loss">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="damageDescription" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And their associated Java classes:

```
@XmlType
public abstract class Loss {
    private Date lossDate;
    private String lossDescription;
    //getter & setters w/ JAXB annotations
}

@XmlType
public class AutoLoss extends Loss {
    //AutoLoss-specific fields...
    //getter & setters w/ JAXB annotations
}

@XmlType
public class PropLoss extends Loss {
    private String damageDescription;
    //getter & setters w/ JAXB annotations
}
```

The XML request I'm sending:

```
<testRequest>
    <myLoss xsi:type="propLoss">
        <lossDate>2001-12-17T09:30:47Z</lossDate>
        <lossDescription>test</lossDescription>
        <damageDescription>damageDesc</damageDescription>
    </myLoss>
</testRequest>
```

The Spring bean definition of the `Jaxb2Marshaller`:

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <!-- list of classes... -->
    </property>
    <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/mySchema.xsd" />
    <property name="adapters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.lmig.ContactAdapter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, I'm getting a fault in the response stating: `Unable to create an instance of com.lmig.Loss`. If I remove the `abstract` modifier on `Loss`, the unmarshalled response object is of the base class type (`Loss`). How can I use Spring-WS and JAXB to properly unmarshall subclasses of abstract parent classes?

Answer (score 2):

You have an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on each class in your hierarchy.  Below is a link to an answer where I demonstrate how to mix Inheritance and `XmlAdapter`:

- [How to handle forward references of XML IDREF with JAXB XmlAdapter during unmarshal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617163/how-to-handle-forward-references-of-xml-idref-with-jaxb-xmladapter-during-unmarsh/7639801#7639801)

**For More Information on JAXB and Inheritance:**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Inheritance

**For More Information on JAXB and `XmlAdapter`**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter

Comment: Thanks Blaise. However, I don't think my `XmlAdapter` is the cause of this. I get the same error when JAXB tries to unmarshall a subclass that doesn't have `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on it. I have updated my original question to reflect this, so hopefully I'm more clear.

Comment: @holic87 - Is your `JAXBContext` aware of the subclasses?  You can either pass them in as a parameter when you create the JAXBContext, or add an `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation to the `Loss` class that references all its sub classes.

Comment: Yes, I've included the list of classes  in the `propertiesToBeBound` property of my `Jaxb2Marshaller` Spring bean, including all base and subclasses. Additionally, turns out I was incorrect in saying that a `null` object is unmarshalled if I remove the `abstract` modifier from the base class: turns out _just_ the base class is being unmarshalled. I've updated my original question to reflect this.