# jaxb marshalling self relation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Consider the known employee/manager relation ship

```
public class Employee
{

public Employee manager;
public List<Employee> employees;

}
```

what i want is a way to marshall an employee such that all the child employees will be marshalled, the parent manager employee also be marshalled. without an infinite cycle loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7639801/4074715

Comment: How do you want the XML to look? Particularly for the `manager` property for the root object.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan , the structure doesn't matter , what i want for the employee  is to marshall parent and child. and i am asking if there is a way.

Answer (score 3):

As explained [here](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html#_XmlID_and__XmlIDREF), you can use the `@XmlIDREF` annotation to avoid cyclic references.

Add a unique identifier to your employee and annotate it with `@XmlID`, and annotate your possible cyclic references with `@XmlIDREF` :

```
@XmlRootElement
class Employee {
  @XmlID string id;
  @XmlIDREF Employee manager;
  @XmlIDREF List<Employee> _employees;
}
```