# JAXB: undefined id "" when unmarshal

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

Saying my xml should look like the following:

```
<!-- even I move <A id="2">...</A> here, still has this error-->
<A id="1">
    ...
       ... (many levels of nested element)
       <C>
           <B ref="2"/>
       </C> 
    ...
</A>
<A id="2">...</A>
```

So I define the following xsd file:

```
<xs:complexType name="A" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
    ...
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:IDREF" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

But When I want to parse this xml file using JAXB, It always complains that `<B ref="2"/>` has a error of:

> Undefined ID "".

My code:

```
public class A {
  private String id;

  @XmlAttribute
  @XmlID
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  ...
}

public class C {
  private A b;

  @XmlIDREF
  @XmlElement
  public A getB() {
    return b;
  }
}
```

So what's the problem?

I have already read [this blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html), [this blog](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617163/how-to-handle-forward-references-of-xml-idref-with-jaxb-xmladapter-during-unmars), not found any clue of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through one whole days search and trials, I finally found the error and solve it:

What class `C` actually has is not directly a `A`'s ref, but a class `B` which only has a ref. So the solution is clear now:

Either to change the xsd to:

```
<xs:complexType name="C">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="B" type="xs:IDREF"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Or to change the java code:

```
public class C {
  private B b;
  ...
}
// addint a B class which contains the reference
public class B {
  private A b;
  @XmlIDREF
  @XmlElement
  public A getB() {
    return b;
  }
}
```

If you are interested how I solve this, you can refer to [my blog](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/01/jaxb-problem-list.html#map-id-and-idref).